# PostBuildEvent error copying config file

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to build my project and getting this error:

```
Error   148 The command "copy "C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\eFormsSystem\eFormsApp\Debug.config" "C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\eFormsSystem\eFormsApp\bin\Debug\eFormsApp.exe.config"
copy "C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\eFormsSystem\eFormsApp\Debug.config" "C:\Users\agordon\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\SubversionRepository\Internal Application\eFormsSystem\eFormsApp\App.config"" exited with code 1.   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets    3397    13  eFormsApp
```

here is the compiler generated code for this copying process:

```
 <Target
        Name="PostBuildEvent"
        Condition=
        "
            '$(PostBuildEvent)'!=''
            and
            (
                '$(RunPostBuildEvent)'!='OnOutputUpdated'
                or
                '$(_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile)'!='$(_AssemblyTimestampAfterCompile)'
            )
        "
        DependsOnTargets="$(PostBuildEventDependsOn)">

            <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)" />

    </Target>
```

the error points to this line:

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" Command="$(PostBuildEvent)
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run the `copy` command by hand?

Comment: i tried it in command prompt and there was no problem, just asked if i wanted to overwrite the file and i said yes

Comment: i forgot to mention this solution is stored in a repository

Comment: The file is marked read only.

Comment: see [Post Build Exited with code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310126/post-build-exited-with-code-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the source config file did not exist (I had custom build profile). Once I copied that config file from another known good one and modified it for my environment, everything started working.