# Build exited with code 1

Tags: c#, wix

When building a Custom Action DLL with the WiX Toolset, I always get the error:

> The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin..\sdk\MakeSfxCA.exe" "Z:\backend\SetupParseConnStr\obj\x86\Debug\InstallerCA.CA.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin..\sdk\x86\SfxCA.dll" "Z:\backend\SetupParseConnStr\obj\x86\Debug\InstallerCA.dll" "C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\SDK\Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll;C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices\15.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll;Z:\backend\SetupParseConnStr\CustomAction.config"" exited with Code 1.

I already found [Post Build exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310126/post-build-exited-with-code-1) but I don't find where to check/change that command line, because I have no commands in post-build.

Comment: It might be already in use ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin..\sdk\MakeSfxCA.exe
```

needs a backslash after bin

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin\..\sdk\MakeSfxCA.exe
```

My guess is that you have explicitly set a property in your .wixproj to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\bin
```

and you need to modify that to end with a backslash.