# Problems while Importing a C++ managed dll to C#.NET Project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, dllimport

It seems like a duplicate question from the title, but let me clarify that I have already searched and followed different methods.
Basically I have to import a `managed C++ dll` into a `C#` project. I consulted some tutorials and finally created a `managed C++ dll`. Now while importing the `dll` I got the following error:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

I found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a) **but these solutions could not help me**. Before facing this error I had to consult [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003072/unable-to-load-dll-module-could-not-be-found-hresult-0x8007007e) solution and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310126/post-build-exited-with-code-1) one too.

Here's a screenshot of how I am trying to import the `dll`:

**Settings:**

[image: Importing the dll fine using build settings]

**Code:**

[image: Calling the dll in the code]

Someone please guide me about the right way to import the `dll` in my project.

Comment: Just FYI, "Managed C++" is only a thing prior to Visual Studio 2005. With VS2005, Microsoft introduced C++/CLI and the syntax is significantly different.

Comment: If you habe a C++CLI DLL, why don't you reference it directly? You would need that anyway for accessing the functions of that DLL. Your build event seems useless to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This C++ library is for certain architecture (x64 or x86). C# on the other hand is not(Any CPU), that is why this kind of error - C# most likely assumes You have a x64 unmanaged library. You should restrict the architecture in C# project to either of these (x64 or x86) so in both projects they are the same.

Comment: I have tried both of them but I am still facing the error

Comment: You have to be sure that both projects have the same architecture and that the function GetRegistryPath is properly exported from your unmanaged DLL! Because "Bad image" most likely means architectures do not match!

Comment: One more thing - You should include file extension in DllImport attribute see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.dllimportattribute(v=vs.90).aspx and as Niall said - if indeed the dll is managed You should add it to references of C# project.

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be copying the file as a pre-build step? Make sure it is in the correct location before the build. I would also remove the `exit 0`, it's not needed.

That `DllImport` is usual for native C-style APIs, not the managed and C++/CLI assemblies. These .Net assemblies, be they mixed mode or not, can be added in the usual assembly dependency locations.

If this is a "Managed C++" and not a "C++/CLI" assembly, it may also be incompatible with the target .Net framework.